# Проблема со считываением клика Android

Tags: java, android, android-on-click, setonclicklistener

Здравствуйте. Наткнулся на такую проблему:
имею 3 кнопки(ImageButton), необходимо после 1-ого нажатия на одну из кнопок,отследить послеующее нажатие(OnClick) на следующую кнопку(допустим-2).3-я не подойдет. Как отследить первый клик,я понимаю.Но как отследить вторую в нужную позицию,нет P.S. Создаю шахматы,пытаюсь реализовать перемещение фигуры посредством изменения ImageButton по клику

Comment: Точнее как отследить именно 2-ое нажатие по экрану

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*@Андр* спросил, как программно реализовать перемещение фигур? Я решил написать алгоритм. Начнем!

1. При нажатии на клетку обращаемся к массиву поля и определяем, какая фигура там стоит. Записываем значение в `int1` (пешка - `1`, конь - `2`, ...) и позицию фигуры в `int2` и `int3` (лучше в формате двух цифр - к примеру `4` и `2`).
2. Если нажатая клетка пуста, ничего не делаем, в противном случае ждем нажатия другой клетки - клетки хода.
3. При нажатии на клетку хода строим `switch` - смотрим, может ли туда ходить фигура. Тут и пригодится созданный `int`. Если все правильно, то проводим вторую проверку - занята ли та клетка? Делаем это через массив. Принимаем окончательное решение и производим (или не производим) перемещение фигуры. Изменяем массив фигур. Стоит учесть, чей ход!!!

Стоит заметить - изначально *массив создается по правилам шахмат* - происходит расстановка фигур. Приведем пример выполнения алгоритма в начале игры.

1. Пользователь нажал на пешку с позицией D2. Записываем в `int1` значение `1`, в `int2` значение `4`, в `int3` значение `2`.
2. Пропускаем.
3. Проверяем в `switch(int1)` значение. Так как оно равно `1`, то смотрим возможные ходы для пешки. Она удовлетворяет требованиям. Происходит ход и запись новой позиции фигуры в массив.

Answer (score 1):

Это можно сделать посредством создания дополнительной переменной; можно создать класс, который будет ее хранить, а можно сделать это прямо в классе активности. Вот алгоритм действий:

- Создаем переменную *button* со значением *false*.
- При нажатии первой кнопки меняем ее значение на *true*.
- При нажатии на вторую кнопку:

  - Если у *button* значение *false*,ничего не делаем.
  - Если у *button* значение *true*, выполняем необходимое Вам действие и ставим переменной *false*.

Comment: Это понятно,спасибо. У меня на экране щахматное поле,состоящее из ImageButton. Как мне после нажатия на кнопку с фигурой(например,пешкой) отследить последующее нажатие на кнопку выше,а другие кнопки в зачет не шли.Тобиш на экране у меня их 64 всего кнопки. Интересует в большей степени именно эта проблема

Comment: Сделайте массив поля. В нем отслеживайте их текущие позиции, в зависимости от них постройте алгоритм. Также будет очень удобно отслеживать клетки, недоступные для хода. А Ваши кнопки пусть обращаются к определенному элементу массива, соответствующему нажатой кнопке. Не забудьте поставить галочку рядом с ответом!

Comment: Также будет очень удобно отслеживать клетки, недоступные для хода. В этом и проблема что не могу реализовать это программно))Все что вы написали выше я уже сделал))Может подскажете как реализовать программно именно отслеживания НУЖНОГО нажатия клетки

Comment: Сейчас напишу еще один ответ.